# Do I need to override the equals method of a class <A> to get unique objects in a Set<A>?

Tags: java, set, equals

Maybe this question should be divided into two, but the first one is quite simple, it's about `.equals()`. I thought that == checks if two references point to the same object, while `.equals()` checks if their parameters' values are the same, as explained here:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/409507/java/java/Difference-equals

But then I tried running this:

```
public class EqualsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i1 = new Integer(1);
        Integer i2 = new Integer(1);
        System.out.println(i1.equals(i2));

        Nested n1 = new Nested();
        Nested n2 = new Nested();
        n1.i = i1;
        n2.i = i2;
        System.out.println(n1.equals(n2));
    }
}

class Nested {
    Integer i;
}
```

And I get as output:

```
true
false
```

As expected when reading Javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

So, from my understanding, to make `.equals()` differ from ==, we need to override it. **Right?**

My second question is, is there any way of making objects from a class `<A>` to be unique (automatically overriden when calling `add()`) in a `Set<A>` without overriding the method .equals() in `<A>`?

Comment: Please be careful to override `hashCode` in addition to `equals`.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't override equals, the class doesn't belong to me. I'll have to do it some other way.

Comment: One hack I can suggest is using a `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator`. Of course, if you don't have an ordering for the items, this in not an option. In that case you can make your wrapper object which will implement equals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> to make .equals() differ from ==, we need to override it. Right?

Yes that's right.

> is there any way of making objects from a class  to be unique (automatically overriden when calling add()) in a Set without overriding the method .equals() in ?

If you don't override equals, then each new instance will appear unique from the set's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure your objects act correctly in all cases you should implement `equals`, `hashCode` **and** make it implement `Comparable` by implementing a `compareTo`.

Remember that `HashSet` uses `equals` and `hashCode` but `TreeSet` uses `compareTo`.

Answer (score 1):

While overriding .equals() is part of the process, you **also** have to overwrite hashCode().

In a set, especially `HashSet`, the .hashCode() method is called to get the hashcode, and then, only if two object have the same hashCode are they then checked for .equals().

You should read the documentaion on the `equals/hashcode` contract here:

- [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)
- [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)